# Profiling memory usage in python generators

Tags: python-3.x, memory, profiling

I'm trying to figure out where my memory is being used in a generator function in python 3.  I've tried memprof and memory_profiler, and both fail to give me information on generators.

How do I determine where, and how much, memory I am allocating inside a generator function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet should work in python3. If you replace the generator function with a list you will see a large difference in memory allocation.

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

print(f'Memory usage after: {memory_usage()}MB')

def obj_generator(num_objects):
    for i in range(num_objects):
        new_obj = {
            'id' : i,
        }
        yield new_obj

objects = obj_generator(1_000_000)

print(f'Memory usage before: {memory_usage()}MB')
```